# FlexSlider2 with thumbnail control navigation pattern

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

I want to use the FlexSlider with the "thumbnail" control navigation. The problem I can not solve is: the active full sized image is not identical with the active image in the thumbnail navigation (not synchronous).

Clicking at a thumbnail will show the **previous** image and - identical to this behaviour - the **previous** thumbnail is highlighted and not the thumbnail of the current shown image.

Using Bootstrap 3.2.0, jQuery 2.1.1 and FlexSlider 2.2.2.

The following HTML code will be generated:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <ul class="slides" style="width: 1200%; -webkit-transition: 0s; transition: 0s; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-803px, 0px, 0px);">
      <li class="flex-item clone" data-thumb="/thumbnail/2014-07-13 09.16.49.jpg" style="width: 803px; float: left; display: block;">
        <img src="/fullsize/2014-07-13 09.16.49.jpg" draggable="false">
      </li>
      <li class="flex-item clone" data-thumb="/thumbnail/2014-07-13 09.16.49.jpg" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 803px; float: left; display: block;">
        <img src="/fullsize/2014-07-13 09.16.49.jpg" draggable="false">
      </li>
      <li class="flex-item flex-active-slide" data-thumb="/thumbnail/2014-07-07 09.52.56.jpg" style="width: 803px; float: left; display: block;">
       <img src="/fullsize/2014-07-07 09.52.56.jpg" draggable="false">
      </li>
      <li class="flex-item" data-thumb="/thumbnail/2014-07-09 16.22.35.jpg" style="width: 803px; float: left; display: block;">
        <img src="/fullsize/2014-07-09 16.22.35.jpg" draggable="false">
      </li>
      <li class="flex-item" data-thumb="/thumbnail/2014-07-11 14.28.42.jpg" style="width: 803px; float: left; display: block;">
        <img src="/fullsize/2014-07-11 14.28.42.jpg" draggable="false">
      </li>
      <li class="flex-item" data-thumb="/thumbnail/2014-07-13 09.16.49.jpg" style="width: 803px; float: left; display: block;">
        <img src="/fullsize/2014-07-13 09.16.49.jpg" draggable="false">
      </li>
      <li class="flex-item clone" data-thumb="/thumbnail/2014-07-07 09.52.56.jpg" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 803px; float: left; display: block;">
        <img src="/fullsize/2014-07-07 09.52.56.jpg" draggable="false">
      </li>
      <li class="flex-item clone" data-thumb="/thumbnail/2014-07-07 09.52.56.jpg" style="width: 803px; float: left; display: block;">
        <img src="/fullsize/2014-07-07 09.52.56.jpg" draggable="false">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
    <li>
      <img src="/thumbnail/2014-07-07 09.52.56.jpg" draggable="false" class="flex-active">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="/thumbnail/2014-07-09 16.22.35.jpg" draggable="false" class="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="/thumbnail/2014-07-11 14.28.42.jpg" draggable="false" class="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="/thumbnail/2014-07-13 09.16.49.jpg" class="" draggable="false">
    </li>
  </ol>
  <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
    <li><a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and this is the jQuery for the FlexSlider:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: "thumbnails",
    start: function() {
      // get the height for the iFrame from the first image of the slide!
      var height = $('.flexslider img').first().height();
      var frame_id = window.frameElement.getAttribute('id');
      var content_height = height + 60 + 0 + "px";
      parent.document.getElementById(frame_id).style.height = content_height;
    }
  });      
});
```

I get no error message and I can not see see any problem with the code. The `start` function in the jQuery is used to set the height of the used iFrame, disabling this function does not change the behaviour. Any idea or a hint for me?

**EDIT** - this is the HTML *source*:

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li class="flex-item" data-thumb="/thumbnail/2014-07-13 09.16.49.jpg">
        <img src="/fullsize/2014-07-13 09.16.49.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li class="flex-item" data-thumb="/thumbnail/2014-07-07 09.52.56.jpg">
        <img src="/fullsize/2014-07-07 09.52.56.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li class="flex-item" data-thumb="/thumbnail/2014-07-11 14.28.42.jpg">
        <img src="/fullsize/2014-07-11 14.28.42.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li class="flex-item" data-thumb="/thumbnail/2014-07-09 16.22.35.jpg">
        <img src="/fullsize/2014-07-09 16.22.35.jpg" />
      </li>          
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: You have eight images in `ul.slides`, but only four in the `ol` following it … I doubt that this’ll work. Why do you have the thumbnail navigation in your markup anyway? You can have FlexSlider create that itself, see example at http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html (after all, that’s the reason for putting the `data-thumb` attribute on the `li`, otherwise that would be pointless.)

Comment: This is the _generated_ HTML code, the source is as in the example (generated by a twig template), the only difference is an additional class "flex-item" for the `<li>` element. The source has only 4 images, they are inserted duplicated by FlexSlider?!

Comment: Ah OK, and I also see the class `clone` on half of the `li` now – Flexslider duplicates items (not necessarily all of them, but at least some) to be able to seamlessly scroll beyond the first resp. last item. Can you show an actual (working) example of the HTML code you are using, a fiddle or something?

Comment: I have added also the HTML source to the question!

Comment: The thumbnails are arranged in another order than the images, is this the reason?

Comment: They should be in the original order. I used FlexSlider 2 recently in a project exactly like that, and did not encounter any such problem. Are you sure that the `data-thumb` of each item matches the actual image? (In both naming, and actual image content.)

Comment: Looking if the thumbs and the images are matching was the first thing I have done ... I have also switched to jQuery 1.11.0 - no change in behaviour. The FlexSlider is also not starting with the first image and ignores the parameter `startAt` ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in FlexSlider 2.2.2 - a downgrade to FlexSlider 2.2.1 solve this problem.

In the current GitHub repository this problem is already fixed, so the coming FlexSlider 2.2.3 will also work as expected.